# How to get Bill Of Material Products on Website

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

How can I show BOM products information on Website(Odoo 10 CE), like product name, desctiption, qty etc

[image]

I tried following but it doesn't work

`<t t-esc="mrp.bom.sudo().product_qty"/>`

and

```
<t t-foreach="bom.product_id" t-as="product">
<t t-esc="product.product_qty">
</t>
</t>
```

But it is not working and giving Internal Server erorr and Error to render compiling AST
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'product_id'

What is the right way to access BOM products on website?

Thanks

Comment: any help please?

Comment: Worked for me, Try this,
```<t t-foreach="product.bom_ids" t-as="bom">
<t t-foreach="bom.bom_line_ids" t-as="line">
<t t-esc="line.product_id">```